# javascript regex to allow numbers and specific special character

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to get a regex to check for only numbers and commas so for example

This will go through

```
1
0,3,4
1,3
1,3,15,12
```

This will not go through

```
abc
1,,3,,4
1,3,
,1,1
```

My current regex is

```
/[0-9]*[,][0-9]*/
```

it doesnt seem to work as what i wanted
Can i get some help thanks

Comment: what is your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Regex `^([0-9]+,)*[0-9]+$`

```js
var re = new RegExp('^([0-9]+,)*[0-9]+$');
function check(){
    var str=$('#hi').val();
    console.log(str);
    if(str.match(re))
    $('#result').html("Correct");
    else
    $('#result').html("InCorrect");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="hi">
<button onclick="check()">Check</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I'm glad I could help.  @DragonKnight

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex like this:

```
^\d+(,\d+)*$
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/MZURSA/1)**

Comment: Did you forget a * at the end? This will match 1,22 and not 1,2,3.

Comment: @Onyambu as far as I understood value `1,22` is a correct match

Comment: You have editted it. Before the edition the regex could not be able to match 1,2,3..but now it can match because of the *

Answer (score 1):

**Regex**: [`^\d+(?:,\d+)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/loyKsB/1)

```js
var array = ['1', '0,3,4', 'abc', '1,,3,,4', '1,3,', ',1,1'];

for (var i of array) {
  console.log(i + ' => ' + /^\d+(?:,\d+)*$/g.test(i))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't Regex, but here is a way to do it:

```js
// Your test input values (which I will assume are strings for this code):
/*
 * 1
 * 0,3,4
 * 1,3
 * 1,3,15,12
 */
 
 const str = '1,3,15,12';
 const isValid = str.split(',')
   .map((val) => !isNaN(parseInt(val)))
   .reduce((currentVal, nextVal) => currentVal && nextVal, true);
   
 console.log(isValid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current regex: `/[0-9]*[,][0-9]*/` 
will match
,

1,1

,6

4953,5433

5930,

etc.

Assuming you want to match a comma-separated list of numbers (each with any number of digits),
You would need:
`/\d+(,\d+)*/`
where `\d` is shorthand for `[0-9]`:

`/[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*/`